# Not getting updates in MVC View following a post method

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Not getting updates in MVC View following a post method

Hi,

Here's my controller code:

```
public ActionResult Search()
{
    ForecastManagementViewModel viewModel = new ForecastManagementViewModel();
    viewModel.JobDate = System.DateTime.Now;

    return View(viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(ForecastManagementViewModelPost model)
{
    ForecastManagementViewModel viewModel = new ForecastManagementViewModel();
    viewModel.JobDate = model.JobDate.AddDays(20);
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

The problem is that when the new view is returned it doesn't contain the updated date value.  (By the way, there's a jquery EditorTemplate behind this DateTime type).

Here's a bit of the view code:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm())
      { %>
<fieldset>

    <legend>Search Criteria</legend>

    <div class="divFirstColumn">
        <div><%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.JobDate) %></div>
        <%= Html.EditorFor(m => m.JobDate) %>
    </div>    

</fieldset>

 <% } %>
```

Any ideas where I might be going wrong.  I'm using MVC2 under Visual Studio 2008 SP1.

Cheers,

J Dubs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be a form mismatch issue... could you check the ID on the client side by doing view source to make sure it will properly hook up to the model when posting?  Also, I would check, using a breakpoint in the post, the form collection to see what the key is on the server-side also.  THe form collection is available as a property of the controller too.

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for getting back so quickly.  I've checked the markup and can confirm that the correct name is being used.  I'll try to simplify the problem into a mini-project to see if there's perhaps some side-affects from the rest of the project.  In the meantime, and other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I've now created a test project and zipped it up.  Can I upload this to stackoverflow?  Perhaps in encoded form - it's a 13k zip that shows the problem clearly.

Comment: Found the answer at: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/05/05/asp-net-mvc-s-html-helpers-render-the-wrong-value.aspx